# Creating a UI to Print a Report in Access 2013

Tags: c#, html, ms-access, user-interface, report

I have a carefully formatted report in Access 2013 and I'm trying to create a UI that will print this report upon a button click.  I would be open to a C# WPF or Form app or perhaps an HTML page that could contain this button.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so what the code would be?

My end goal is to have the user be able to print this report without having to access the database directly.  I am open to other languages/platforms.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day you still need Access installed, and at the end of the day you still have to launch Access, and at the end of the day you still 100% relying on Access.

Thus to print an Access report you still have to launch Access. It not at all clear why then you cannot built your required UI in Access since you still 100% relying on Access for this report.

You thus will have to automate Access and rely on Access. You can use any system or language that supports COM object automation.

So in say windows scripting, you could go:

```
Dim app        As Object

Set app = CreateObject("access.application")

app.OpenCurrentDatabase ("path to database")
app.DoCmd.OpenReport ("ReprotName")
app.CloseCurrentDatabase
app.Quit
```

The above same code would work in vb.net. Note that the “default” to open the report will send it to the printer without preview.

Also keep in mind that since you are creating an instance of the Access application, then all of the startup code and forms will launch and run. If such startup code and the startup form being run requires ANY user interaction, then the above will not work. Because of the above “many” issues, you likely best create an application that has linked tables to the data, and contains your required report. This approach will thus avoid all of the existing application code and startup forms running.

So in any case you WILL have to launch the application and deal with all of the startup forms etc. As noted, often then it makes sense to copy out the report to a separate application with linked tables for your purpose.

Keep also in mind that the Access runtime (as opposed to full version) does not support nor allow use of CreateObject - you have to resort to shell() with startup parameters to launch + run the report.

Last but not least, you can from the Access UI simply DRAG the report to your desktop. The result is a one click button on your desktop that will launch the report in question.